# How is validity consensus implemented in Corda?

Tags: block, blockchain, corda

I am trying to understand the concepts of corda. I understood that for a transaction to pass a validity consensus, parties should check all the transactions of the particular assest till the issuance transaction.
[Described Here.](https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-consensus.html#validity-consensus)

But how is this actually implemented in code? Do we have to write the logic ourselves or it is handeled by flow framework itself?

Answer (score 1):

It have two main concepts:

> The transaction is accepted by the contracts of every input and output state.

This you can visualize in following way. Suppose you have StateA which is handled by ContractA and StateB which is handled by ContractB.
Now suppose you creates a transaction with CommandA and it have both the states i.e. StateA and StateB in your transaction.
Than it is mandatory that you have CommandA in both the contracts and inside that command you validate the transaction and it's state. Therefore making sure that every contract of all the input and output state accepts the transaction.

> The transaction has all the required signatures

This is something which is handled automatically in almost all scenarios. You can use `collectSignature` subflow and than use `verifyRequiredSignatures` to make sure that transaction have all the required signatories. You can find more on this at : [CollectSignaturesFlow](https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.flows/-collect-signatures-flow/index.html) and [Flow cookbook](https://docs.corda.net/flow-cookbook.html)

Walking the transaction chain is handled automatically when a node or validating notary verifies a transaction.